# impossible human verification while on certain mobile devices

Tags: feature-request, bug

Whenever stackoverflow is in doubt, and can't tell if you are a real user or a bot, you get sent to https://stackoverflow.com/captcha.

The rules should of course apply to all entities that SO finds suspicious, but perhaps not through the same method (more specifically; *the same page*).

---

**THE BUG**

While browsing SO from my *BlackBerry*, I wanted to answer a question. For some reason SO thought I was a bot, which I take as a compliment; sadly there's no way for me to get back to "human", since the CAPTCHA form doesn't show up correctly.

[image: Broken captcha]
<sub>(source: [bayimg.com](http://image.bayimg.com/2ef26d1369dad010d29741cfe49833f1b49d1fc9.jpg))</sub>

<sup>*Where's that CAPTCHA?*</sup>

---

**THE FEATURE REQUEST**

A more mobile-friendly CAPTCHA for *"human verification"*, so that all mobile users can prove their innocence.

---

<sup>**Note**: This post was written using my *BlackBerry*, hopefully *meta* doesn't flag me as a bot, but as you are reading this I guess it haven't.</sup>