# Proof that we are human

Tags: feature-request, captcha

I have just received 100 bonus points, because "I am trusted on other sites". Yet, when I asked a question, a day later, I was asked to enter proof that I am a human being...  Why do I have to prove I am a human being? How can a bot use this site?

(My guess for the purpose of a bot possibly using this site would be advertising, but then that user would not have high reputation or have gained points for being "trusted"...)

Wouldn't users with high reputation be automatically considered human(-oid)?

Note - I ran into the same trouble as the user in question *[impossible human verification while on certain mobile devices](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256601/impossible-human-verification-while-on-certain-mobile-devices)*.

Before... And even my first try on a PC did not render... I was able to post after being given a second chance to prove my humanity.

Wouldn't it be easier for users of 500 or 1000 points or above to not have to prove they are human? Or perhaps skip this question based on certain badges?

Comment: Did you just paste the question into the edit box rather than typing it out again?

Comment: No... but I started it last night and came back this morning to finish it, they were kicking me out at work :-) I see that maybe that would have been a trigger

Comment: Hmm. Whenever I've got the captcha it's been because I've pasted the text into the edit box. Perhaps if you take too long (for an unknown value of "long") to submit your question/answer it does the same.

Comment: I had done it before... message gets saved as a draft... Well I also pasted some code into the box of course but I also did a lot of editing and typing around it... I was not asked to prove I was human other times when my question was saved as draft

Comment: It's common enough for a real person to run an account and then start using a bot to automate it, either in part or in full.  That someone has earned some rep simply is not enough to guarantee that they're actually human *forever and ever* even if it's enough to be confident that they were human once upon a time.

Comment: I see... My small human imagination didn't conceive the many ways an artificial being could exploit a feature... That sounds like proof that computers are smarter than humans

Comment: @Thalia: ip address changes are a common trigger.

Comment: That is very helpful to know

Comment: Nice try.. bot.

Comment: @Servy: "*It's common enough for a real person to run an account and then start using a bot to automate it, either in part or in full.*" - really? This something of which I've been blissfully unaware, so far.

Comment: @DavidThomas Common in the sense that a significant portions of actions performed by bots are using accounts once used by people, not in the sense that a significant portion of accounts run by people will later be used by bots.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are already throttles in place based on reputation.

If you have 200 points, you'll be limited to one captcha per 5 minutes at most.

Starting at 10k you'll *very rarely* see the test (you need to post within a second of opening a page or switch IP addresses a lot).

See [Increase captcha threshold for post editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing) and  [I am not a robot!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143455/i-am-not-a-robot)

Comment: This is not my experience: I have 135K points and I get the captcha for every question and it takes many trials to get through the validation process (to the point where it take **longer** to pass this than it took to write the answer) This is **so annoying**.

Comment: @chqrlie as annoying as it might be... probably best to open a new question related to your issue, as it could be related to recent changes in cloudflare rather than commenting on a 9 year old post.

Comment: @KevinB: Of course! if I can get past the captcha :) I was scanning related questions to avoid asking a duplicate one.